# Android NavigationView is causing android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, navigation-drawer

I have created an app and I implemented Theme setting feature in that (User can choose different color for app controls and app UI controls color changes in runtime). As user changes the theme, activity gets recreated(onCreate() method gets called).
In the first invocation of onCreate function everything works fine but when user tries to change app theme in runtime app is crashing and the reason is android.support.design.widget.NavigationView. If I remove NavigationView App doesn't crash.

## LayoutFile

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.byt.store.activities.HomeActivity"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:clickable="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <com.byt.store.util.CircularProgressView
        android:id="@+id/progress_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:cpv_thickness="4dp"
        app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
        app:cpv_animAutostart="false"/>

    <com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/common_pad_50dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/common_pad_50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        fab:type="DEFAULT"
        fab:button_color="?attr/colorPrimary"
        fab:button_colorPressed="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        fab:image="@drawable/pencil_128"
        fab:image_size="24dp"
        fab:shadow_color="#2A2A2A"
        fab:shadow_radius="4.0dp"
        fab:shadow_xOffset="2.5dp"
        fab:shadow_yOffset="2.0dp"
        fab:show_animation="@anim/fab_roll_from_down"
        fab:hide_animation="@anim/fab_roll_to_down" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <com.byt.store.util.drawer_expandable_list.ExpandableListView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/FloatingGroupExpandableListView"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:transcriptMode="disabled"
            android:transitionGroup="false"
            android:smoothScrollbar="false"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

## Logcat

```
06-30 06:52:21.278  21969-21969/com.byt.store E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.byt.store, PID: 21969
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.byt.store/com.byt.store.activities.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #69: Error inflating class <unknown>
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2301)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #69: Error inflating class <unknown>
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
                at com.byt.store.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:96)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5984)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
                at com.byt.store.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:96)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5984)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1240)
                at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:124)
                at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:938)
                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.createDefaultColorStateList(NavigationView.java:338)
                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:124)
                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
                at com.byt.store.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:96)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5984)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2254)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2361)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us the layout.xml that you are inflating inside HomeActivity's onCreate(). The error is in that XML file line #69

Comment: Have you added design support library??

Comment: Yes I added. If I not added It should crash every time right?

Comment: Can you post your theme?

Comment: my theme is as below

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@color/icons</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

Comment: Did you solve this? And how?